# PHP : file upload and database update

Tags: php

Here is the situation :
1. I have a calendar file that is remotely updated on the server by iCal every X time,
2. I have to read datas from this file and update the database.

The problem is that I want to avoid updating database when the file is updated by iCal, because instead of having 5000 entries I will just find 100, 500 or 3000.

Here is a solution I just think about, what do you think of this ? :
Before reading the file, check with filemtime() if last update is between 5 minutes after last update and 5 minutes before the next 'probably' update (because even if updates should normaly be every 15 mins I already noticed that it can be 16, 17, or... 20 minutes)

Comment: I would cron this job to update on a regular schedule, to avoid it running at the same time the file is being written.  Your last update check sounds good too.  What kicks off the update now, a user loading a page?  That sounds performance intensive, would it need recency < 1hour?

Comment: Yes the job will be done via cron. Datas will be displayed on a public page, but parsing directly the ics file is really long for page loading, so a cached request on dbb will probably be faster.
Recency will be at soonest every 15 minutes if changes are made in the source file (iCal)

Comment: what is the question anyway?

Comment: The question is "is it a good way for doing that, or is there a better way ?", or if you prefer "how to avoid updating database when source file is updating ?"

Comment: I do this often with loading inventory, we end up using flat files for some integrations with older systems.  Our timing is a little more controlled than this iCal update process.  With all of our jobs, the first step is to confirm that the file is valid and run a sanity check on it. (make sure it's not being written and is complete data)  The second step is to make a copy, and we process the copy, so that the other process can start writing over the original file and it won't interfere.  After processing, we optionally store x number of files in an archive to inspect if there are problems.

Comment: Nobody taught me to do it this way, I just have always made a copy and processed the copy rather than the original, seemed safer.  It might not be necessary but it's worked for me for years.

Comment: Yeah I think you're probably right with working on a copy.
However, how did you ensure that the file is not written and is complete data ? Because it's finally my first question (but not well formatted :-/)